# ¿Como abrir un modal al ingresar a la web con jquery vs1.12.4?

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Hola estoy tratando de abrir un modal al entrar a mi web, hice un proyecto aparte con jquery v3 y me funciona perfectamente, pero ahora necesito implementarlo en un proyecto que tiene la vs1.12.4 y creo que eso afecta. Este es mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('#modalInfo').modal('show');
        });
    </script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="admin/images/vacunaCovid.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilicé la versión 1.12.4 de jquery junto a la versión 4.6.0 de bootstrap (funciona igual con la v3), algunos detalles en tus etiquetas html del modal y también es muy recomendable utilizar la función `ready`, cuando indica que el documento ha cargado **totalmente**, también verifica que la etiqueta `script` de jquery esté antes de la etiqueta `script` de bootstrap u otras librerias.

Aqui un snipped de ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Título</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Contenido...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```